# map class causes memory leaks

Tags: c++, maps

```
 int main()
    {
    map<string,string> x;
    x["Haitham"]="000@hotmail.com";
    x.clear();

    _CrtDumpMemoryLeaks();
    return 0;
    }
```

> when i test for memory leaks for this program the output is  Detected
>   memory leaks!
>
> {152} normal block at 0x0070ABD8, 8 bytes long.
>
> Data: <4 p     > 34 AB 70 00 00 00 00 00
>
> {151} normal block at 0x0070AB90, 8 bytes long.
>
> {150} normal block at 0x0070AB08, 72 bytes long.
>
> Data: <`p` p ` p     > 60 A9 70 00 60 A9 70 00 60 A9 70 00 01 00 CD
>   CD
>
> {145} normal block at 0x00704C40, 8 bytes long.
>
> Data: <  ^     > E4 FE 5E 00 00 00 00 00
>
> {144} normal block at 0x0070A960, 72 bytes long.
>
> Data: <  p   p   p     > 08 AB 70 00 08 AB 70 00 08 AB 70 00 01 01 CD
>   CD
>
> Data: <  p     > 18 AB 70 00 00 00 00 00
>
> Object dump complete.

Comment: Try adding an extra set of braces around the 3 lines referring to the `map` (or move those to another function).

Comment: Please state a clear question, not just some code and a title

Comment: Well at the point you call the dump function, `x` still exists. So of course the internal `map` allocations will be considered leaked...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This issue is that the you're calling the function that checks for memory leaks too soon.  The `map` hasn't been destroyed at the point you call `_CrtDumpMemoryLeaks`.

Change your code to this:

```
int main()
{
    {
        map<string,string> x;
        x["Haitham"]="000@hotmail.com";
        x.clear();
    }
    _CrtDumpMemoryLeaks();
    return 0;
}
```

This should now show that the `map` is destrouyed, since it is local to the `{ }` block.